# Why my method only runs the first time in a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, methods, while-loop, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a quizz with turtle and pandas libraries, so I put a while loop to run 50 times, and the text input runs well, but the methods only runs the first time, I don't know why, I already search on the web but with no success.

this is on main python file.

```
import turtle
from List import State

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Quizz U.S. States Game")
image = "blank_states_img.gif"
screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)
states = State()
guessed_states = []

while len(guessed_states) < 50:
    answer_state = screen.textinput(f"{len(guessed_states)}/50 Guess the State",
                                    "Whats another state's name? ").title()
    if states.check_if_exists(answer_state):
        guessed_states.append(answer_state)
        states.print_state(answer_state)
```

This is in my class List

```
def check_if_exists(self, a_state):
    if a_state in self.states_list:
        return True

def print_state(self, a_state):
    self.states_list = data[data.state == a_state]
    self.t.goto(int(self.states_list.x), int(self.states_list.y))
    self.t.write(f"{self.states_list.state.item()}", align=ALIGNMENT, font=FONT)
```

the problem is that only runs the first time, If put California its prints on the correct destination, but if I keep writing states it doesn't show anymore.

I want to every time I put down a state in text prompt and if in the list of states prints its name on the map.

Comment: Could you share the rest of List?

Comment: Could you print in the console the result of guessed_states in the while loop?

Comment: @Alex V. This is the rest of my List

`import pandas
from turtle import Turtle

# reading the csv file
data = pandas.read_csv("50_states.csv")
# splitting into states
states_list = data["state"].to_list()
# Constants
ALIGNMENT = "center"
FONT = ("Consolas", 10, "bold")


class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = Turtle()
        self.t.penup()
        self.t.hideturtle()
        self.t.color("black")
        self.states_list = data["state"].to_list()`

Comment: I get an error in print_state, as self.states_list.x does not exist. Did you mean self.states_list["x"]?
If there are any errors showing up in your terminal, please share them, as they really help in debugging.

Comment: @CarlosChaires it's best to [edit] your post to show large blocks of code. It's hard to read it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In print_state you redefine self.states_list and try to call self.states_list.x and self.states_list.y, which are not existing properties. self.states_list.state.item() is also not an existing method. When you post questions, always add the error messages that you get when you run the code. Make sure to read up on pandas dataframes and how to access specific elements.

I modified your code a bit so that it works. It now checks if the string is indeed a valid state. If it is, and it has not already been found, it will call print_state, but now it will get the x and y coordinate from the dataframe, without changing the self.states_list variable.

```
import turtle
import pandas
from turtle import Turtle
# reading the csv file
data = pandas.read_csv("50_states.csv")
# splitting into states
states_list = data["state"].to_list()
# Constants
ALIGNMENT = "center"
FONT = ("Consolas", 10, "bold")


class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = Turtle()
        self.t.penup()
        self.t.hideturtle()
        self.t.color("black")
        self.states_list = data["state"].to_list()
        print(self.states_list)

    def check_if_exists(self, a_state):
        if a_state in self.states_list:
            return True

    def print_state(self, a_state):
        # Get the row index for the state that was found.
        index = data[data['state'] == a_state].index[0]
        # Get the coordinates for that state
        coords = [data["x"][index], data["y"][index]]
        # Go to the coordinates
        self.t.goto(int(coords[0]), int(coords[1]))
        # Write the state name
        self.t.write(f"{a_state}", align=ALIGNMENT, font=FONT)


screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Quizz U.S. States Game")
image = "blank_states_img.gif"
screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)
states = State()
guessed_states = []

while len(guessed_states) < 50:
    answer_state = screen.textinput(f"{len(guessed_states)}/50 Guess the State",
                                    "Whats another state's name? ").title()

    if states.check_if_exists(answer_state):
        if answer_state in guessed_states:
            print("You have already guesses that one!")
            continue
        guessed_states.append(answer_state)
        states.print_state(answer_state)
    else:
        print('Wrong answer.')
```

Maybe try restructuring your code a bit, so that you have a Quiz class, instead of the State class that you use at the moment.
You can store the found states in the Quiz class itself and get rid of multiple copies of the list of states.